# hot-proxy does not handle `$app-css-relative-asset-path` properly

Tags: shopware, shopware6

When I use the bin/watch-storefront.sh my custom font does not load properly.

My fonts are defined like the default font in a own file like

```scss
/* /MyTheme/src/Ressources/app/storefront/src/scss/vendor/_outfit-fontface.scss */
...
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Outfit';
    src: url('#{$app-css-relative-asset-path}/font/Outfit/Outfit-SemiBold.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('#{$app-css-relative-asset-path}/font/Outfit/Outfit-SemiBold.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap;
}
...
```

When I run `bin/console theme:compile && bin/console assets:install` The fonts get loaded just fine on the regular website.
The URL of the font files is like `https://my-site.de/theme/f9cf8c2bbd24d1ca2941b5120cde3278/assets/font/Outfit/Outfit-Regular.woff2`

But when I run the `hot-proxy` via `bin/watch-storefront` the compiled CSS font path is like `http://my-site.de:9998/bundles/storefront/assets/font/Outfit/Outfit-Bold.woff2`
I looked into the directories and my fonts are not located in `storefront/assets` but in `mythemeplugin/assets`

The wrong path seems to be exported to `/var/theme-entry.scss` where it already sets the `$app-css-relative-asset-path` to

```scss
$app-css-relative-asset-path: '/bundles/storefront/assets'; $sw-asset-public-url: '';
```

I tried to replace the variable `$app-css-relative-asset-path` with a hard-coded `../assets/` in my *-fontface.scss but this will cause a compile error in the hot-proxy.

What can I do to make the fonts load properly in the hot-proxy and the normal site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/shopware/platform/issues/1910) with a possible workaround.

Adding to the description, you'll have to change the type of your `style` property in `theme.json` to an object:

```json
{
  // ..
  "style": {
    "app/storefront/src/scss/overrides.scss": [],
    "@Storefront": [],
    "app/storefront/src/scss/base.scss": {
      "resolve": {
        "my-theme-env": "app/storefront/env/default"
      }
    }
  },
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm having issues with the part where her replaces '"app/storefront/src/scss/base.scss"' in the `theme.json`. I end up with a invalid JSON file and I get a comple error that says: @import '~my-theme-env/scss/variables'; Can't find stylesheet to import.`  Not sure what changed in theme.json since he wrote the post.

Comment: Yes, you'll need to change the type of the `style` property to be an object with key value pairs to keep the json valid. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I figured this out too. but the error still is the same. I first try to resolve this on the github issue, and update here later if I find a solution.

Comment: I can happily tell that I finally got it working. The missing bit was to run `bin/build-storefront.sh` after applying the workaround.